# Oracle apex: Javascript to display sum of a column in an interactive report based on a checked checkbox row

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I have an interactive report with a check box (`selectunselectall`) and column2 (`countthisrow`) having numbers. I need to display sum of column2 in a text item after the interactive report when a row in column 1 is checked. I assigned a static id to column2 but couldnt figure out how to write a dynamic action with javascript.

```
<tr>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="selectunselectall" headers="selectunselectall"><input name="f01" type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="C4665519416385240" headers="C4665519416385240">id1</td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="countthisrow" headers="countthisrow">1</td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="C4665768588385242" headers="C4665768588385242">abcd</td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="C4665808804385243" headers="C4665808804385243">a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="selectunselectall" headers="selectunselectall"><input name="f02" type="checkbox" value="2"></td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="C4665519416385240" headers="C4665519416385240">id1</td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="countthisrow" headers="countthisrow">2</td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="C4665768588385242" headers="C4665768588385242">abcd</td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="C4665808804385243" headers="C4665808804385243">a</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ur Html 
i am taking a div to show the value give an id to this div

```
<div id="total">Total val: </div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="selectunselectall" headers="selectunselectall">
      <input name="f01" type="checkbox" value="1" id="f01">
    </td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="C4665519416385240" headers="C4665519416385240">id1</td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="countthisrow" headers="countthisrow">1</td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="C4665768588385242" headers="C4665768588385242">abcd</td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="C4665808804385243" headers="C4665808804385243">a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="selectunselectall" headers="selectunselectall">
      <input name="f02" type="checkbox" value="2" id="f02">
    </td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="C4665519416385240" headers="C4665519416385240">id1</td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="countthisrow" headers="countthisrow">2</td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="C4665768588385242" headers="C4665768588385242">abcd</td>
    <td class=" u-tC" aria-labelledby="C4665808804385243" headers="C4665808804385243">a</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

ur javascript

first call the id of element then create a addEventListener to capture its value
take a total variable where i assign the value of selected checkbox and then appear it to the total div

```
const checkbox1 = document.getElementById('f01')
const checkbox2 = document.getElementById('f02')
const totalVal = document.getElementById('total')

var total = 0;

checkbox1.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  total += parseInt(event.target.value)
  totalVal.innerHTML = total
})

checkbox2.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  total += parseInt(event.target.value)
  totalVal.innerHTML = total
})
```

Hope its helps if you need anything else u can tell. Thanks